# Postfix server: Mailman email double checked with SpamAssassin

Tags: postfix, spamassasin, mailman

I have set up postfix with spamassassin, and then added mailman for mailing list management, everything on Debian 9 Stretch:

postfix: 3.1.8
mailman: 2.1.13
spamassassin: 3.4.1

The problem is that the mail that is reinjected by MailMan is re-checked by SpamAssassin for each single recipient of mailing lists, which puts quite some burden on the system. Since the mail is already checked when originally accepted, I would like to circumvent the second spam check.

The configuration is as follows:

Mailman has `MTA='Postfix'` in the `mm_cfg.py` file.

## Postfix

### main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman
```

### master.cf

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    ....
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
smtps      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    ....
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    ...
    -o content_filter=spamassassin
    -o receive_override_options=no_milters


...
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

What would be a possible way to make SpamAssassin skip the check on email delivered from MailMan?

Comment: AFAIR you can create exception rules in mailman. You might not however be interested in doing that. If your mailman is compromised the SpamAssassin rules might catch some of the outgoing spam